# whats the suggested order of extracting dimension/fact data?

Tags: data-warehouse, etl

My understanding says that the dimensions should be extracted first, then the facts should be extracted. That way, the foreign keys will still be honoured in staging area.

While loading, the same sequencing should be used, for the same obvious reasons.
Therefore. the final order should look like this -

extract dimension -> extract fact -> load dimension -> load fact

While I was going through DAC documentation, I came across a piece where it says that the order should be like this =

extract fact -> extract dimension -> load dimension -> load fact

Ideas/suggestions/opinions..

Answer (score 4):

I suspect that the author's idea may be: when you load new data, first identify the facts you are interested in to make sure you process and load the minimum amount of data. Then derive your dimensions from those facts, so you populate only dimension values that you actually need.

I have no idea if this interpretation is correct, but I could imagine someone making that argument. On the other hand, it's often very interesting to know which dimension values have no corresponding facts, e.g. which customers have not bought a new product yet.

So exactly how you process the data in your environment will depend a lot on your own requirements, and I wouldn't worry too much about what a single document says.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a bit too late, but just in case someone runs into this question, here is some clarification.

Data warehouses typically are built on a storage system which does not enforce referential integrity, either because it's an inherent characteristic of it (Redshift, Hive, etc) or because if the system allows it (like a classic RDBMS), they would cause additional overhead/performance impacts.

As such, the proposed order of

`extract fact -> extract dimension -> load dimension -> load fact`

aims to guarantee the referential integrity is kept.

If we extract facts first, we will make sure that once we extract dimensions, all the facts will point to a valid dimension/existing dimension in the warehouse.

By loading dimensions first (assuming a Kimball modelling methodology), once you load the facts you will be able to join them with a conformed dimension and successfully retrieve the dimension surrogate key.